# Consistency in a matrix, given an unkown variable $k$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification

I have a matrix $A = $$ \left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  1&2&3&-17\\
  -2&-4&-k&34
\end{array}
\right] $$ $ and want to check for consistency of the system for the possible values of $k$.

I am, however unsure if my answer is correct:

$$ \left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  1&2&3&-17\\
  -2&-4&-k&34
\end{array}
\right] $$

$$ \left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  1&2&3&-17\\
  0&0&6-k&0
\end{array}
\right] $$

$$ \left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  1&2&3&-17\\
  0&0&1&0
\end{array}
\right] $$

$$ \left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  1&2&0&-17\\
  0&0&1&0
\end{array}
\right] $$

Am I correct in assuming, that as long as variable $x_3 = 0$, every value of $k$ makes the system consistent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you're correct.

The only trouble that might arise is dividing by $6-k$ during Gaussian elimination, because in the case that $k=6$, that's not justifiable. By examining the case $k=6$ separately though, you can see that the system is still consistent.